# View-trouble in pgAdmin (bad code). Website map not showing correctly

Tags: postgresql, view, pgadmin

I have a website that I want to show childcare institutions in the municipality. I had the correct visualization, but I went and accidently deleted the view.
The view read from 7 different tables.

I have tried to recreate the view-code and have come up with this:

```
SELECT 
    dag_adressedar_241123.geometri AS wkb_geometry,
    dag_daginstitution_241123.daginstitutionsnummer,
    dag_daginstitution_241123.daginstitutionsnavn,
    dag_daginstitution_241123.ejerkode,
    dag_ejerform.ejertxt,
    dag_daginstitution_241123.lovgrundkode,
    dag_lovgrundlag.lovgrundtxt,
    dag_daginstitution_241123.kommunekode,
    dag_daginstitution_241123.senestopdateret AS dagins_senestopdateret,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.anvisningsenhedsnummer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.anvisningsenhedsnavn,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.dawaid,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.vejnavn,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.husnummer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.supplerendebynavn,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.postnummer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.bynavn,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.etage,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.doer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.vejkode,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.insttype3,
    dag_instype.instypetxt,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.email,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.telefonnummer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.cvrnummer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.pnummer,
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.senestopdateret AS anv_senestopdateret
FROM 
    cup_dagtilbud.dag_daginstitution_241123
LEFT JOIN 
    cup_dagtilbud.dag_anvisningsenhed_241123 ON dag_daginstitution_241123.daginstitutionsnummer::text = dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.daginstitutionsnummer::text
LEFT JOIN 
    cup_dagtilbud.dag_ejerform ON dag_daginstitution_241123.ejerkode = dag_ejerform.ejerkode
LEFT JOIN 
    cup_dagtilbud.dag_lovgrundlag ON dag_daginstitution_241123.lovgrundkode = dag_lovgrundlag.lovgrundkode
LEFT JOIN 
    cup_dagtilbud.dag_instype ON dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.insttype3 = dag_instype.instypekode
LEFT JOIN 
    cup_dagtilbud.dag_adressedar_241123 ON dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.vejkode = dag_adressedar_241123.vejkode
WHERE 
    dag_anvisningsenhed_241123.kommunekode = 173;
```

However, when I go look at the website now it looks like this:

[Seems empty until I open table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbp1u.png)

It is empty. However, when I click the tables it does show data, however it is highly duplicated and there are way too many points (which makes sense because there are so many duplicates) and the symbol does not look correct (It is supposed to be a pram). It looks like this:
[How the map looks when opening the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MywW2.png)
[Legend is showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8342e.png) . Nothing is wrong with my presentation. It is the view code, I think. The main problem is that i get many rows that are identical.

Can someone tell if there is a problem with my code? It runs without problems, but it is not showing properly.